# How to unmarshall CDATA field in XML using Rest Template

Tags: xml, unmarshalling, resttemplate, cdata

I'm having this issue for hours, and I can't seem to find any articles that would solve my problem.

So I'm trying to store the XML that is being responded when I call a `getForObject` in my object created.

Here is the XML response that I am trying to store in my object to map it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>        
<data contentType="text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" contentLength="138">       
<!        
[CDATA[[       
{    
    "categoryCode":"Exp Prtnr Def",    
    "code":"EXP",    
    "value":"30",    
    "version":1,    
    "effectiveStartDate":"17-02-2017",    
    "effectiveEndDate":"02-12-2290"    
}     
]]]     
>     
</data>
```

and here are my code statements which calls I try to store in my Object Class.

```
JSONMapper response = restTemplate.getForObject("http://{IPAddress}/CodeDecode/getCodeValueList?categoryCodeList=Exp+Prtnr+Def", JSONMapper.class);
```

and here is my `JSONMapper` class

```
public class JSONMapper implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String data;

    public JSONMapper()
    {
    }

    public JSONMapper(String data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getData() 
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) 
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code, it generates this error.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of com.org.mappers.JSONMapper out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@22d9d; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of scom.org.mappers.JSONMapper out of START_ARRAY token
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@22d9d; line: 1, column: 1]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:622)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:580)
>       at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:287)
>       at sg.gov.ntp.tx.uve.controller.test.main(test.java:13)
>   Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.org.mappers.JSONMapper out of START_ARRAY token

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I put the data field as `string` as I've come to an understanding that `CDATA` is of `string` type.

I'd like to add that when i try restTemplate.getForEntity(...), it returns an empty body and can't seem to get the CDATA fields.

I am not sure why this is happening. Could someone please help me in solving this issue I'm having?

It is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know resttemplate but why are you using jackson and a jsonmapper? You try to unmarshal xml right? Use jaxb!

Comment: I was just told that we need to consume JSON response. what i need to do right now is to get the CDATA field as i'm still getting an empty response body when printing it